# Página de Login

Tags: html, angular, adminlte

Estou aprendendo angular.

Estou usando o angular 6

Estou tentando fazer a página de login do Admin LTE

Importei esses arquivos no angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"
        ]
```

Mas a área cinza do fundo não está funcionando em toda a página e parece que nem o bootstrap está funcionando, enquanto que esta mesma importação funciona para a página em geral, mas quero deixar o login bem formatado, assim como é no original

Esta é a minha configuração

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cinza ficou na metade da página

E esse é o original

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo bem formatado

E esse é o código que inseri login.component.html

```html
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

    <form action="../../index2.html" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
      <p>- OR -</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in using
        Facebook</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Sign in using
        Google+</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

    <a href="#">I forgot my password</a><br>
    <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

</body>
```

Aqui está o [projeto](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/adminlte)

Aqui tem a [pergunta](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/adminlte/issues/1)

Aqui está o [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w545n)

Comment: Tenta criar um stackblitz com seu código, vai ser difícil alguém conseguir responder sem conseguir inspecionar o dom.

Comment: como faço pra enviar meu projeto pra la?

Comment: Cria um novo projeto angular la e copia o minimo possível pra reproduzir seu problema.

Comment: Estou tentando e não estou conseguindo

Comment: Acho que consegui mais ou menos.. [Aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w545n)

Comment: Nao entendi qual o problema? O que esta errado no stackBlitz?

Comment: Não está formatando corretamente, creio que ele não esteja detectando o bootstrap

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/login.html) e outra, lá mostrou o background normal, mas no meu, aquela cor de background vai só até metade da página

Comment: Aqui para mim no Stack Blitz está normal http://prntscr.com/kixuh9

Comment: Só no meu projeto está ficando [assim](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/adminlte/issues/1)

Comment: @adventistaam tente outro navegadores e compare o código com o original do Admin LTE.

Comment: Sim eu testei. Estão do mesmo jeito

Comment: Sem simular o erro fica meio complicado de entender o por que do erro, tente inspecionar os elementos e verificar o motivo de estar quebrando.

Comment: No stackblitz não está pegando as fontes de redes sociais... nem formatando o checkbox pelo que eu percebi

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81707/discussion-between-paulo-henrique-and-adventistaam).

Answer (score 0):

Eu tinha este mesmo problema no AdminLTE, por alguma razão o tamanho da div `login-box` não está indo até o final do navegador. Eu apenas troquei o elemento `body` do index.html para isso:

`<body class="hold-transition fixed sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse" style="background:#d2d6de;">`

Edit: sua cor é a default, eu tinha clareado um pouco mais o fundo.